# How to fix Failed updating Service : The container XXX did not have a container port 80 defined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I have a `ecs` cluster and have some services running, and I needed to update the `container port` from `80` to `7001`.

So I tried creating a new revision of the `task definition` but I get the below error:

[image]

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I have similar issue, don't know how to resolve that. I want to switch to EKS immediately :D.

Comment: I know it is been over 1 year old question but I am going to post the solution anyway

The issue is that your load balancer configured with you service is targeting the container on that port.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error because the load balancer associated with the ECS service is targeting the container on port 80 while your container is not exposing port 80. In order to resolve this you have two options

**Solution #1**

In your task definition file (json file) you need to add the port mapping to allow traffic to your container on port 80.

```
"portMappings":
[
    {
        "containerPort": 80,
        "hostPort": 80,
        "protocol": "tcp"
    }
],
```

**Solution #2**

Update the load balancer associated with your ECS service to target the container on the specified port which is in your case `7001`

Please note: Load balancing settings can only be set on service creation. This means you have to re-create the service

Comment: if you add the port mapping to 80, the container is not using 7001?